# Regex email validation simple modification

Tags: regex

I have found this regex online regarding HTML email address match :

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^`{|}~_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\w+)+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,3})+
```

Somehow, I try to modify it in order to exclude email addresses that has only a special character ( repeated or not )

like these :- _@test.com, ____@test.com, +_@test.com

https://regex101.com/r/MLfxNK/4

Comment: See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nGf21a/1). `[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^\`{|}~_-]+` => `[0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^\`{|}~_-]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^\`{|}~_-]*` and `(\w+)+` must be written as `\w+`. And add anchors if you need to match them as whole strings (if your method does not ensure that).

Comment: Why don't you want to accept emails from `someone@something.solutions`? P.S. It doesn't match tlds greater than 3 characters properly

Comment: @Ziko - Personally, if at all possible, I would leave the regex you found alone, and write another one to filter the results out.  It's likely to perform better *and* be easier to read.

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't filter this other than ensuring a `@` exists. Send a test email, if they don't receive it, they'll have to try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This forces there to be at least one letter or number before the `@`. It doesn't otherwise change the emails accepted.

```
[.!#$%&’*+/=?^`{|}~_-]*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^`{|}~_-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9-](\w+)+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,3})+
```

Actually I prefer zzxyz's solution: use an ordinary email address validator, then filter out those with only special characters.